# Bluetooth connected thread instantly closes socket after connection

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, kotlin, bluetooth

I have an Android app targetting the latest at the type Android API (29). The user has the ability to search for nearby bluetooth devices and connect to them to send data. The bluetooth connection is made with the app being the client.

I copied much of the code from Anroid's documentation and changed it to fit my needs. The app does find the devices, pairs correctly and connects.

**The problem is that right after it has connected, on the first loop in the Connected thread when it tries to read for incoming stream, an exception is thrown and the socket disconnects.**

I have connecting directly to the correct uuid for the device, to test if the looping through the possible server bluetooth uuids might interfere with the rfcomsocket.
I tried in the connected thread in the loop to check for `mInputStream.available() > 0` before trying to read, but it appears that it throws an exception there too.

To test the connection I activate my laptops bluetooth adapter and set it to receive a file(as a server). I used to have this app in Xamarin.Android and the code used to work that way. Currently it runs in Kotlin.

The code bellow shoes the Connect and Connected threads, called from the according functions.

```
fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice, uuids: ArrayList<ParcelUuid>) {
    if (connectionState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread?.cancel()
            connectThread = null
        }
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread?.cancel()
        connectedThread = null
    }
    connectThread = ConnectThread(device, this, uuids)
    connectThread?.start()
}


private inner class ConnectThread(
    val device: BluetoothDevice,
    service: BTService,
    val uuids: ArrayList<ParcelUuid>
) : Thread() {

    var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null

    init {
        service.connectionState = STATE_CONNECTING
    }

    override fun run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
        btAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

        for (uuid in uuids) {
            try {

                val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket? by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
                    device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid.uuid)
                }
                mmSocket?.use { thisSocket ->
                    // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
                    // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
                    thisSocket.connect()

                    // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
                    // the connection in a separate thread.
                    socket = thisSocket
                    connected(thisSocket)
                }
                break
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Close the socket
                cancel()

                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect() to socket.", e)
            }
        }
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    fun cancel() {
        try {
            socket?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e)
        }
    }
}


//#####################################                     #####################################
//#####################################----->Connected<-----#####################################
//#####################################                     #####################################

// Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
fun connected(socket: BluetoothSocket) {
    // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread?.cancel()
        connectThread = null
    }

    // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread?.cancel()
        connectedThread = null
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    connectedThread = ConnectedThread(socket)
    connectedThread?.start()

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    MainActivity.settingsFragment?.activity?.runOnUiThread {
        (MainActivity.settingsFragment as SettingsFragment).btConnected()
    }

}

private inner class ConnectedThread(private val mmSocket: BluetoothSocket) : Thread() {

    private val mmInStream: InputStream = mmSocket.inputStream
    private val mmOutStream: OutputStream = mmSocket.outputStream
    private val mmBuffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024) // mmBuffer store for the stream

    init {
        connectionState = STATE_CONNECTED
    }

    override fun run() {
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream.
            try {
                mmInStream.read(mmBuffer)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                connectionLost()
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e)
                break
            }
            //Do something with stream.
        }
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
    fun write(bytes: ByteArray) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e)
            // Send a failure message back to the activity.

            return
        }
    }

    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    fun cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e)
        }
    }
}

// Stop all threads.
fun stop() {
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread?.cancel()
        connectThread = null
    }

    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread?.cancel()
        connectedThread = null
    }

    connectionState = STATE_NONE
}

fun write(bytes: ByteArray) {

    if (connectionState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
        return
    }
    val temp: ConnectedThread? = connectedThread
    temp?.write(bytes)
}

fun connectionLost() {
    MainActivity.settingsFragment?.activity?.runOnUiThread {
        (MainActivity.settingsFragment as SettingsFragment).btLost()
    }
    connectionState = STATE_NONE
}
```

Th result is a IO catch from the connected thread due to the crash when trying to read. I would expect it to just loop in an active connection, and if if any data are transmitted to be sent to me.

I am aware that the inputStream is not saved anywhere (it is intentional), but I doubt that is the problem.

***Edit 1:***
The debug log from the connection start to connection failure(end)...

```
2019-08-03 18:30:40.583 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
2019-08-03 18:30:40.776 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@39f9369, channel: -1, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@611f1ee, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@96eb68fmSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@15d7d1c impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@94fd25 fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@42f3efa, mSocketState: INIT
2019-08-03 18:30:40.780 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug E/BluetoothService: unable to connect() to socket.
    java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:762)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:776)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:399)
        at com.konkarapas.rcs.models.BTService$ConnectThread.run(BluetoothService.kt:172)
2019-08-03 18:30:40.782 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
2019-08-03 18:30:40.934 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@5534f08, channel: 4, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@ebd46a1, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@3a250c6mSocket: android.net.LocalSocket@fdce887 impl:android.net.LocalSocketImpl@f5253b4 fd:java.io.FileDescriptor@cc6abdd, mSocketState: CONNECTED
2019-08-03 18:30:40.938 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@5534f08, channel: 4, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@ebd46a1, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@3a250c6mSocket: null, mSocketState: CLOSED
2019-08-03 18:30:40.943 24961-25089/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug D/BluetoothService: Input stream was disconnected
    java.io.IOException: socket closed
        at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:104)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.read(BluetoothSocket.java:555)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothInputStream.read(BluetoothInputStream.java:88)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.konkarapas.rcs.models.BTService$ConnectedThread.run(BluetoothService.kt:245)
```

The first exception is logical due to the wrong uuid. The second exception is the problem.

Comment: No exception stacktrace?

Comment: The only exception thrown is from the ConnectThread when it tries to connect to the device. That is only once exception due to trying to find the correct uuid. In the current device the uuid is in the second position in the array (uuid[1]) and so it has to fail once. This is handled.
The only other exception thrown is in the ConnectedThread which is the problem. I edited the question above with the whole Debug log from the connect button click, up to the failed connection message.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `mmSocket?.use`, which cleans up after itself after it is done (ie. closes the connection) If you change that to, say, `mmsocket?.let`, it should not autoclose the connection after it is done. (had the exact same problem with network socket, fixed it like this)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. I also tried removing the lazy wrapper from the socket creation, with no results. The stacktrace is the same and the problem persists. Thank you for your awnsr though :)

Edit: I was using mmSocket?.use as this is the recommendation on Android docs!
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#ConnectAsAClient

Comment: Ok, ater a lot more testing it appears that mmSocket?.use was part of the problem but it was not the only problem. I will come back with an ansewr when I know exactly how to fix it. Thank you again :)

Comment: hm... Something else is closing your connection then, the line ```2019-08-03 18:30:40.938 24961-25088/com.konkarapas.rcs.full.debug D/BluetoothSocket: close() this: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket@5534f08, channel: 4, mSocketIS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream@ebd46a1, mSocketOS: android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream@3a250c6mSocket: null, mSocketState: CLOSED``` would indicate just around where that happens, but I can't find the part where that is actually being logged.

Comment: I'm not very good at threads, but i'd think closing the thread that has your active socket in it might have something to do with it. Good luck anyway!

Comment: As you mentioned, the above stacktrace indicates that the socket is closed twice. One was the .use, the other was when it was closing the Connect thread for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

So, after some digging into Kotlin and JVM and lots of debugging I found the problem.
It appears that just like Java, Kotlin is pass-by-reference.

That means that when you pass a non primitive (any custom class) object into a function, it just references that object into the function. That means that any changes done to the object into the function, even after the function exits, are done to the "parent object" too.

**The problems:**

In my case, the were two problems. The first problem as mentioned by @Joozd was the use of `mmSocket.use`. It closed the socket right after the connection

The second problem was the `connected()` function. It was created to close the `ConnectThread` and keep only a single `ConnectedThread`. Instead, when it closed the socket in the `ConnectThread` it closed the socket passed to the `ConnectedThread` too.

**The solution:**

Changed the `mmSocket.use` to `mmSocket.let` to not automatically close the connection.
And deleted unesessary function `connected()` and moved the contents right after the connection is established. The null checks are done in the `connect()` functions anyway at the start of the connection.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I just lost 3 hours over this issue. Had no idea why the connection was getting closed automatically. Your answer helped me. Thanks for this.